# How do i make an option for Celsius or Fahrenheit with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, web

I created a Laravel project which first shows you a combobox with months, it then sends you to the page with the selected month, on this page it shows the weather statistics for this month, my task is to add 2 radio buttons , one that when pressed shows the statistics in degrees celcius and the other one when clicked shows the degrees in fahrenheit,

to be honest i don't really know how to approach this matter.

I've looked online how you would change from celcius to fahrenheit but i didn't really find anything propper to help me.

this is the page that it starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- selecteer.php -->
<html lang="nl">
    <head> <!-- VIEW -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Temperaturen</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="overzicht" method="post">
            Maand: <select name="maand">
            <option value="1">Januari</option>
            <option value="2">Februari</option>
            <option value="3">Maart</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit">Overzicht</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

you select a month (the months are in dutch) and then when you click on the button you go to "Temperatuur.php"

```
<?php # app\Temperatuur.php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Temperatuur extends Model
{
 static public function getData($maand = 0)
 {
 $dagtemperaturen = DB::table('dagmeting')->where('maandnr','=',$maand)->get();
 return $dagtemperaturen;
 }
}
```

on this page it shows a table filled with the temperature stats of the selected month, and it shows the month at the top.

```
<?php # app\Http\Controllers\TemperatuurController.php
 // CONTROLLER
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Temperatuur;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class TemperatuurController extends Controller
{
 public function getIndex()
 {
 return view('selecteer');
 }
 public function overzicht(Request $request)
 {
 $maand = $request->input('maand');
 $metingen= Temperatuur::getData($maand);
 return view('overzicht', array('maand'=>$maand, 'metingen'=>$metingen));
 }
}
```

^^ this is the controller for temperatuur.php

i really dont know how to approach this matter , i know you need to do something with javascript, but i really dont have a clue what..

Answer (score 0):

@Sjoerd,

I'll try to help you with this conceptually -

1. You would need to update your `get temperature data` method to accept an input parameter, which could either be Celsius or Fahrenheit, along with the city name.
2. The code in this method will get temperature for that city (let's assume base calculation is in Celsius).
     **2.1.** If Fahrenheit is passed to this method, you would only have to [convert the temperature to Fahrenheit](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20celsisus%20to%20farenheit&oq=convert%20celsisus%20to%20farenheit&aqs=chrome..69i57.5915j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and return the value.
3. On page load, you could call this method and pass in a default temperature metric.
   **3.1.** You could set the default page load metric to Celsius and let the user select Fahrenheit metric from the radio button if he/she wishes to change.
   **3.2.** (Future) You could potentially store this user selection as a browser cookie so the next time this page is loaded, you automatically show the temperature in the metric the user last selected.
4. If the user updates the radio button to select Fahrenheit, you only have to call the method (explained in point 2) above and pass 'Fahrenheit' to the method as a parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please tell me how to start off with updating the get temperture data?